# Blazor Web App (.Net 8) with oidc loses auth when switching to client

Tags: blazor, openid-connect

I am trying to set up a web app that uses OIDC to authenticate to an identity server.
I can authenticate but all api calls return 401

I used the microsoft example as a base but am completely lost on how to include my auth props in my calls to the api.

The API responds with the following:
[image]

I can see that the call to the weather api has cookies but the call to the api has nothing.

I created a repo with basic example code : https://github.com/malfaitbart/oidcdemo

Any help would be appreciated